# Добавление панели расширенного форматирования текста

Tags: javascript

Скажите, как решить такую проблему. Как в поле комментариев сделать функции форматирования, такие как: курсив, жирный шрифт, вставка ссылки, нумерованный список, вставка смайлов и всё в подобном роде? По возможности, поясните решение более подробно.

Answer (score 1):

То, что вы ищете, зовется [WYSIWYG-редактор](http://www.google.ru/#q=wysiwyg+редактор). По ссылке вы можете выбрать тот, который вам больше по вкусу.
Мне лично больше понравился [elTRE](http://elrte.org/).

Comment: СПАСИБО))) Очень рад))) Всё поставил)))

Answer (score 0):

[ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) использую у себя в проектах